# Green's theorem in vector analysis

Tags: vectors, greens-theorem

I have tried working it out, but I don't seem to know how to use the y2=2x.

- the question is asking:
  Evaluate the integral
  $\int(x^2-2xy)dx + (xy^3+3) dy$ around the boundary of the region bounded by y^2=2x and x=2
  Directly and using the Greens theorem.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: ʃ(x^2-2xy)dx + (xy^3+3)

Comment: I edited your previous comment into the question body. I am not sure what you mean by y2=2x. Please [edit] your question to correct it.

Comment: the boundary of the region bounded by y^2=2x and x=2